# Prefix for testing methods in Unit: "test" vs "should"

Tags: java, junit, naming-conventions, junit4

It is a common practice to prefix the tests method names in JUnit with "test". But in the last few years, some people changed this to the prefix "should".

If I want to test the customer creation in a database, I would normally name the method "testCustomerCreation". However, some people would name "shouldCreateCustomer".

This is a lot of personal taste when I am the only person in the project or when everyone else in the project agrees with me. But when/where this is not the case, some divergences or inconsistent mixes starts to shows up.

I readed somewhere an article of a guy that named his methods like "testShouldCreateCustomer", and for this reason he decided to drop the "test" prefix. But in fact he wasn't prefixing with "test", he was using "testShould" and changed to "should". Obviously, this did not convinced me.

I am personally strongly inclined to stick to "test" prefix because the methods names normally starts with verbs in the infinitive form ("get", "set", "add", "remove", "clear", "send", "receive", "open", "close", "read", "write", "create", "list", "pop", "print", etc, so is "test"). So, prefixing a method name with "should" makes it sound really very strange for me, looks wrong.

So, what is the real good reason to use "should" instead of "test"? What are the great advantages and disadvantages?

Comment: I'd spend less time worrying about silly prefixes and more time worrying about the rest of the test name being descriptive.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The 'Should' convention is aligned with the [behaviour driven development](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behavior_Driven_Development) style of testing.

I personally really prefer to write tests in this style, as it encourages you to write tests that **read as specifications**, and are more aligned with the **behaviour** of the class or system that you are testing.

Where possible, I sometimes go one step further and give the test class even more context using it's name:

```
class ANewlyCreatedAccount {
  shouldHaveAZeroBalance() {}
  shouldCalculateItsOwnInterest() {}
}
```

By naming your classes and thinking about them in this specification style, this can give you a lot of guidance on **which tests to write**, and **in which order** you should write the tests and make them green.

Yes, 'should' vs 'test' is just a prefix and it's important to be consistent, but this question is also about the style and mindset of how you test your code and choose which tests to write.  BDD has a ton of value, so I suggest reading further and give this a try.

Comment: +1 for mentioning that it's about behaviour rather than testing methods

Comment: Ok, you are convincing me. But, this means that all the people that simply name test methods that does not even looks like to specification of anything (like "shouldSaveUserToDatabaseWhenPasswordIsChanged"), are people who simply does not know what they are doing? If the test method particularly has nothing to do with BDD (like a test that guards against a bug that occurred in very peculiar combination of conditions), should it still be prefixed with "should"?

Answer (score 5):

I would say the 'test' prefix is simply a holdover from the pre annotation days when that was required.  I would suggest you simply use meaningful names for your test cases (and that may mean with or without 'test').

I prefer to name the test method so that it is clear what is being tested.  i.e.

```
checkNullParameter()
runSimpleQuery()
runQueryWithBadParam()
```

All the test cases are located in a test directory anyway and all actual tests are annotated, so the 'test' prefix is rather redundant.

Comment: runQueryWithBadParam() - You aren't saying what you expect here though.  I'd personally prefer to see shouldThrowBadParamExceptionOnBadParam().  Should also encourages you to describe your expectation......

Comment: The annotation (expected=BadParamException) should be clear enough for the simple case.  In other cases I let the code show what I expect, as there might be several assertions made with regard to multiple bad parameters.  For example null, or an out of range value might both be contained within the same testcase (bad param).  The assertions themselves tell what I am expecting and should be clear to anyone reading the code.

Comment: @Benjamin: What about testQueryWithBadParam()?
@Robin: I partially agree. Sometimes "check" or "verify" is better than "test", but "runSimpleQuery" is not exactly what you does. You don't simply run it, you run and asserts that it runned correctly, so would be like "testSimpleQueryRun". Equally we would have "testQueryWithBadParam". I know that this way it is very likely that every method will have the prefix test, but it would not be simply a prefix, it will be part of the description of what the method does.

Comment: @Victor - I think @Test testThisThing() is redundant.  The annotation already determines the methods purpose is to do a test.  I don't think having the same prefix on every method that is already annotated to be a test is very useful, whether that prefix is 'test', 'should' ... or anything else.

Answer (score 3):

Consistency is more important than being correct on naming issues. If there is any question on a project, the technical member responsible for the project should outline the coding practices formally so that issues like this don't kill valuable project time.

Comment: "Consistency is more important than being correct" - story of my company's 1.5 million line ERP software in one sentence.

Comment: on _naming_ issues. There are certain things worth spending time discussing and finding best practices. Arguing over brace placement, capitalization scheme, and test prefixes don't fall into that group. Overgeneralizing and poorly applied advice might be more of your software's issue.

Answer (score 3):

In the original JUnit, test methods had to begin `test`. A lot of frameworks for other languages copied this convention. Even though it's no longer the case in JUnit, and even though other frameworks may be different, I think most programmers are still pretty familiar with methods named e.g. `testX` as being unit tests, so I think it's good to stick to the `test` convention for that reason.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer the `test` suffix. It's possible that you might have a method with a prefix of `should` in your project e.g. `shouldBuy` and your test would then be called `testShouldBuy` because `shouldShouldBuy` would just look very strange.

I also use the [`MoreUnit`](http://moreunit.sourceforge.net) Eclipse plugin which will automatically create a test method prefixed with `test` when I press `Ctrl+U` or jump to the test method when I press `Ctrl+J`. (Although you can configure which prefix it uses.) If you are not consistent with your naming, automated tools such as MoreUnit won't be able to help you with your testing.

Comment: Naming a test method according to the tested method should be avoided after all, since this lead to refactoring hell, so this argument is not really valid.